# What's wrong with this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Person (name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.sayName = function () {
            alert(this.name);
        }
    }    
    var person1 = new Person ("tom", 29);
    var person2 = new Person ("frank", 21);
    alert(person1.sayName==person2.sayName);

    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That depends on what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? What is happening instead?

Comment: Dreamweaver says I have a syntax error in line 7( this.name = name;). So what is the syntax error. Thanks

Comment: When you're asking questions about books, please include information about the work. It helps people help you, as well as correctly attributing the code. In this case, the example is from *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, Second Edition* by Nicholas C. Zakas (Wrox, 2009), pages 152-154.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it (other than the slightly pedantic missing semicolon on line 6.)

Because the `sayName` function is created inside the constructor, a new function is created every time a new object is created. (So the functions are different, and `==` returns false)

People get around this by attaching the function to the prototype object instead:

```
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}    

Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
    alert(this.name);
};

var person1 = new Person ("tom", 29);
var person2 = new Person ("frank", 21);
alert(person1.sayName==person2.sayName);
```

This will create only one function (saving you memory) and the alert will say 'true'.

Comment: Can I change Person.sayName = function(){alert(this.name)} to 
Person.prototype.sayName = function(){alert(this.name)}?

Comment: Ahah, wow. Yeah my bad that was a typo. It is meant to be `Person.prototype.sayName`. I edited it to be correct.

Comment: So is there any difference between Person.sayName and Person.prototype.sayName?

Comment: If you do `Person.sayName` then `person1.sayName` === `undefined`, but `Person.sayName` will be the function. If you do `Person.prototype.sayName` then `person1.sayName` will be the function, and `Person.sayName` === `undefined`.  I was basically attaching the `sayName` function to the `Person` function, rather than the prototype.

Comment: If I write the code this way:                                function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    sayName = function() {
         alert("hello");
} 
}                                                                    Does sayName here really mean something? If it does, what is the difference between sayName and this.name? Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: If you write it like that then you 'clobber' the global namespace, you need to put a `var` infront of `sayName`.
If you do that, then the variable becomes local to the constructor function, and you can only access it from within there, it essentially becomes a private function.

Comment: @jsnewman: Here is something you can have a look at that might be interesting http://jsfiddle.net/b26mc/

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the function pinters, not the results.

Try:

```
alert( person1.sayName() == person2.sayName() );
```

But then again: your sayName() triggers another alert(). What is this code all about??

Answer (score 1):

`person1` and `person2` are different objects, so their comparison *should* be `false`.

However, you may have meant to compare the functions literally, which you can with `toString()`, in which case, the alert is `true`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3RQ3c/).

And of course, they both have a different `this.name` so if they did return that, and you called the functions and compared them, it would be `false` as well.